# Reversing an Order in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to teach myself Haskell and I am fairly new so I was wondering if someone could help me out. I'm trying to write a function that reverses the order of a name so that if I type,

```
ghci> fullName "harry" "potter"
```

I should get,

```
"potter, harry"
```

What I've tried:

I know that to print out the first two chars, I need to do

```
initials :: String -> String -> String
initials firstname lastname = [l] ++ [b] ++ ", " ++ [f] ++ [a]
        where (f:a:_) = firstname
              (l:b:_) = lastname
```

and this will get:

```
ghci> initials "harry" "potter"
"po, ha"
```

It works, but the problem is that it needs to work when you don't know how many chars are in a name. I should be able to enter any random name no matter how long and it should be able to reverse the order. I feel like it's something incredibly obvious, but I am not getting it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`String` is a type alias for `[Char]`, so you can use `++` with it

```
fullname :: String -> String -> String
fullname first last = last ++ ", " ++ first
```

Answer (score 4):

First, as a tip, you could write what you have more idiomatically as

```
initials (f:a:_) (l:b:_) = [l, b] ++ ", " ++ [f, a]
```

But this is what is known as a partial function (not to be confused with partial function application).  Here I mean that a function can be partial or total.  If a function is total, then it is defined for all possible values of its input types.  `initials` is not defined for the input `initials "" ""`, for example, so you would get a pattern match error, indicating that it is not total.  More mathematically, it means that for `f :: A -> B`, for all `a` in `A`, there is a `b` in `B` such that `f a = b`.

There are two (common) ways to implement something like this.  You could use more pattern matching like

```
initials [] [] = ", "
initials [a] [] = ", " ++ [a]
initials [] [b] = [b] ++ ", "
initials (f:a:_) (l:b:_) = [l, b] ++ ", " ++ [f, a]
```

Or you could use the built-in function `take`:

```
initials firstname lastname = take 2 lastname ++ ", " ++ take 2 firstname
```

The second is much cleaner and avoids worrying about matching every pattern, but sometimes pattern matching is definitely the way to go.

For working with names of arbitrary length, since `String` is the same as `[Char]`, you can just use `++` like you are already with `++ ", " ++`:

```
fullname firstname lastname = lastname ++ ", " ++ firstname
```